# Wordpress UT Strange Theme Header Error

Tags: php, wordpress, header, themes

I'm currently experiencing a problem with this theme on my site. A para of code has appeared at the top of the site and no code has been amended. I've looked in the header.php but cant see anything obvious.

http://www.tccars.info/

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: have you added anything in with wp_head?

Comment: No :( I've even reuploaded an old backup of the header.php file but its still displaying the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please add your all jquery files in Footer.

Thanks

Comment: Hi Sorry could you explain in a bit more detail please? I've copied an old working version of the footer from the dev platform onto the site but its still displaying the same error.

Comment: There seems to have been some injected code, Ive taken this out which hasnt affected the styling but there is still a page not found error at the top, any ideas?  http://www.tccars.info/